# Conexão com Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com um problema em fazer a conexão com o Banco de Dados Mysqli,
está dando vários erros, segue os erros abaixo:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\web\localuser\riobonitopiscinas\www\acessorios-para-construcao.php on line 63
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\web\localuser\riobonitopiscinas\www\acessorios-para-construcao.php on line 66
PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\web\localuser\riobonitopiscinas\www\acessorios-para-construcao.php on line 84
```

E o meu código da página é:

```
<?php
   include ('admin/include/conexao.php');

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id_subcategoria=78");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<?php include ('includes/box.php'); ?>

<?php                       
   }  
   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

O meu código da conexão :

```
<?php

$parseini = parse_ini_file('admin/ini/config.ini', true);

$dsn = sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s',$parseini['bancodedados']['dbname'], $parseini['bancodedados']['host']);

try {
    $conexao = new PDO($dsn, $parseini['bancodedados']['usuario'], $parseini['bancodedados']['senha']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: "*estou com um **problema em fazer a conexão** com o Banco*", se o problema é com a conexão, você precisa nos mostrar o arquivo que faz a conexão. Todos os erros citados são de objeto nulo, o que indica que sua variável `$con` é nula.

Comment: <?php
$parseini = parse_ini_file('admin/ini/config.ini', true);

$dsn = sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s',$parseini['bancodedados']['dbname'], $parseini['bancodedados']['host']);

try {
 $conexao = new PDO($dsn, $parseini['bancodedados']['usuario'], $parseini['bancodedados']['senha']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>

Comment: @Vinicius, coloque o código da conexão na pergunta em si e não aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Pronto esta na pergunta

Comment: Você conecta o banco em `$conexao`, mas utiliza `$con`? Por que isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tem dois erros no teu código.

1. Já foi apontado por outros usuários nos comentários é que você está inicializando a conexão com o mysql e guardando isso na váriavel $conexao (no arquivo conexao.php), na hora de utilizar a conexao tu usa a váriavel $con que nem existe no seu código.
2. Tu abre uma conexao utilizando PDO como conexão e depois tu utiliza métodos do mysqli. PDO e Mysqli são duas formas de se conectar no banco em php, escolha uma e utilize ela.

Se tu mudar a conexao para mysqli deve funcionar já que tu utiliza os métodos do mysqli no outro arquivo, segue aqui em baixo utilizando mysqli para se conectar.

conexao.php

```
$parseini = parse_ini_file('admin/ini/config.ini', true);

$con = mysqli_connect($parseini['bancodedados']['host'], $parseini['bancodedados']['usuario'], $parseini['bancodedados']['senha'], $parseini['bancodedados']['dbname']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Erro ao conectar no mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Link uteis:
[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)
[pdo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

seu código esta com erro na variavel `$con`
note que no seu arquivo de conexão você utiliza `$conexao`

tente desta maneira :

```
<?php
   include ('admin/include/conexao.php');

   $result = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id_subcategoria=78");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<?php include ('includes/box.php'); ?>

<?php                       
   }  
   mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```